# A way to count the number of system processes started in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to get the information about the number of system processes that are started by a shell script during its execution. Additional things like timings would be a *cherry on the cake*.

I'm using linux & bash.

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Look at the `pstree` command.  You might be able to get at what you are looking for.  Also [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852023/how-to-get-all-parent-processes-and-all-subprocesses-by-pstree) gets into the weeds a bit on the subject.

Comment: Thx: I didn't know it. I tried previously with `ps -...f` which provides similar tree information (but much less readable). Both however "take a picture" at a given moment while I would need a historical information as all process doesn't run at the same moment.